# ntp recipe didn't install ntpdate files

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I have included ntp package.

When yocto OS image comes out, it has only ntp, there is no ntpdate.

I found someone has the same problem but no solution:

https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Linux/How-to-install-ntpdate-command/td-p/1052770

Why it has only ntp? The recipe did include ntpdate.

https://git.congatec.com/yocto/meta-openembedded/blob/ddd3ccd63949f9a24040eb39c136ef9730f2662a/meta-networking/recipes-support/ntp/ntp_4.2.8.bb

ex:

```
 install -m 755 ${WORKDIR}/ntpdate ${D}${bindir}/ntpdate-sync
 ...
 install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/ntpdate.service ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ntp` and `ntpdate` are two packages of the `ntp` recipe.
If you want to add ntpdate, just add to your image:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "ntpdate"
```

---

Explanation:
Take a look at the recipe, and at the `PACKAGES` variable:

```
PACKAGES += "ntpdate sntp ${PN}-tickadj ${PN}-utils"
```

It means that the `ntp` recipe contains the packages: `ntp` (default `${PN}`), `ntpdate`, `sntp`, `ntp-tickadj`, `ntp-utils`.

You can also take a look at the environment of the `ntp` recipe:

```
$ bitbake ntp -e |grep ^PACKAGES=            
PACKAGES="ntp-src ntp-dbg ntp-staticdev ntp-dev ntp-doc ntp-locale  ntp ntpdate sntp ntpq ntp-tickadj ntp-utils"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [ntpd manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntpd) where is explained the option `-q` is reported:

> -q
>
> Exit the ntpd just after the first time the clock is set. This behavior mimics that of the **ntpdate program, which is to be retired**. The -g and -x options can be used with this option. Note: The kernel time discipline is disabled with this option.

In my opinion this means that is preferible use the daemon `ntpd -q -g -x` instead of `ntpdate`.