# Install a NTP Client in an yocto-base embedded Linux distribution

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, ntp, yocto-recipe

I'm developing a yocto-base Linux distribution by the **zeus** yocto release.
I need to install a NTP client into the distribution and I don't want to install the NTP server inside the image.

In **zeus** yocto release I have found the following recipe:
`meta-openembedded/meta-networking/recipes-support /ntp/ntp_4.2.8p15.bb`
that is relative to Network Time Protocol (NTP).

The recipe contains following info about itself:

> SUMMARY = "Network Time Protocol daemon and utilities"
>
> DESCRIPTION = "The Network Time Protocol (NTP) is used to
> synchronize the time of a computer client or server to
> another server or reference time source, such as a radio
> or satellite receiver or modem."

Previous information don't explain if the recipe can be use to install, in the distribution, a NTP Server, a NTP Client or both.

What I need is a NTP client application that is able to connect to an external NTP server.

The following instruction:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "ntp"
```

is not suitable because adds to the Linux distribution the NTP Server which is called `ntpd`.

What's the package that I have to add to the image to include a client NTP? Is it included in the previous recipe or I have to find a different recipe?

Thanks

Comment: Just install it, but don't run the service?

Comment: Yes I need only install the client (I think is `ntpdate`). Not the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of the post [ntp recipe didn't install ntpdate files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62441233/ntp-recipe-didnt-install-ntpdate-files) is perfect to solve this problem.

By the instruction:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "ntpdate"
```

in the distribution, are installed only `ntpdate` and the service `ntpdate.service` without installing `ntpd` and its service.

To avoid the installation of the `ntpd` program (NTP Server) it must be removed the instruction:

> ```
> IMAGE_INSTALL += "ntp"
> ```

from the distribution.

### A useful teaching about the installation of packages with Yocto

Very useful the followed comment present in the post: [ntp recipe didn't install ntpdate files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62441233/ntp-recipe-didnt-install-ntpdate-files):

> Explanation: Take a look at the recipe, and at the `PACKAGES` variable:
>
> ```
> PACKAGES += "ntpdate sntp ${PN}-tickadj ${PN}-utils"
> ```
>
> It means that the ntp recipe contains the packages: `ntp` (default `${PN}`), `ntpdate`, `sntp`, `ntp-tickadj`, `ntp-utils`.

This comment helps to learn that in general a recipe can define many packages and *every package contains many programs, configuration files, and so on*.
The assignment `IMAGE_INSTALL += ...` depends on what must be installed.

In the context of this post, where the OP need to install only the NTP client, it must be excluded the default package `ntp` and it must be included the package `ntpdate`.

Comment: Useful the link to the [ntpdate manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntpdate) to know information about ntpdate.